# How do I change the color of inactive fields in Informatica's edit windows?

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

In Informatica Designer and Workflow Manager, when the user opens a transformation/session for edit without having it checked out, all the fields are displayed in a really low contrast shade of grey against the white background.

Has anyone found a way to change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** The original worked somewhat, the real fix is this:

1. Right click on desktop background - select properties.  **This is the windows desktop background, nothing to do with infomatica!**
2. Select Appearance tab
3. Under "Windows and Buttons" select "Windows Classic Style"

---

*Original Answer:*

The problems seems to be that windows based themes are used for the background and white (with no way to change it) is used for the font color.

Here is how I fixed it on windows XP:

1. Right click on desktop background - select properties.  **This is the windows desktop background, nothing to do with infomatica!**
2. Select Appearance tab
3. Select Advanced button
4. Select the Active window (below "Item:" it will now say "Window")
5. Below "Color 1" select some other color than white.

NOTE: This means the default background color for **ALL** programs will now be white.

*C'est la vie*

Answer (score 1):

In case of Windows 7, the only way I found is changing the theme - none of the *Aero Themes* will work and *Windows 7 Basic* is still too fancy. You need to use the *Windows Classic* theme.

**Windows 7 theme**

[image: Windows 7 theme - hardly readable field names]

**Windows Classic theme**

[image: Windows Classic theme - a little improvement]

Answer (score 1):

The color Informatica chose to use for the "checked in" text is from the "Inactive title bar" for som reason. It can be changed through the control panel:

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance`

Click on

`Advanced appearance setting...`

Select

`Inactive Title Bar`

The color you need to change is `Color 1`

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried changing the colors here - Tool > Options > format?

Comment: This does not work... the problem has nothing to do with the obvious options.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar solution and finally the above comment helped me to find the proper solution where I am able to see the port name under inactive transformation window in BLACK.

For windows 7 (similar for other windows system too) , go under appearances setting at

**Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance**

Open advance appearance setting which will open a new window "Window Color and Appearance" . Here we have multiple color combination setting for different type of display items like message boxes , boarders ,menu etc .

Go to **['Inactive Title Bar'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI6PI.png)** change the Color 1 to black from grey. Leave the color 2 field as its is . Apply and see on the other side that your inactive Informatica transformation window's port are now in Black . Clearly visible.

Answer (score -2):

Seriously , Is that a real problem. 
It is good as long as you are able to identify that the object isn't checked out.

Comment: It is nice to be able to browse through fields without having to check each transformation out.